Windows 11 taskbar labels get stuck and don't expand
I'm running Windows 11 23H2 (via a Tiny11 image), and I've set the taskbar behaviour to combine items only when the taskbar is full, as I prefer to be able to identify windows by their title when possible. Most of the time this works fine, but sometimes the taskbar items appear to get stuck when they are first created. They will expand only part way to their full size, obscuring some or all of the title, as show below:

When the taskbar is updated later, eg. if a new window is opened, the items may then resize to look how they should:

This intermittent sizing behaviour seems like a bug to me, and is rather annoying because it can defeat the purpose of me using the full-size taskbar icon setting. Is there a known fix for this, or a third party taskbar tweak that would fix it?
EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm fine with the behaviour in the second screenshot - that's how I'd expect it to look. The first screenshot is what I'd consider to be a bug, because for a window with a full title, the taskbar item should never look like that.

I agree with John. You should also know that Tiny11 or Tiny10 was created to make it as light as possible. As the developer doesn't give any details of all the features it removes from Windows, it's very difficult to know what's causing a problem like yours, for example.
I suspect, however, that a component has been removed from Windows which prevents it from working properly.
Installing an alternative version of Windows is therefore at your own risk.
EDIT:
I confirm what @harrymc said, it doesn't seem to be a bug, I have exactly the same result.


To be clear, I'm not saying what you've posted would be a bug, I'm saying that my first screenshot is, where the item should be sized to show the title.

could you please include a screenshot in your question so that we can clearly identify the result you are looking for, as I don't think we understand your request?

There are two screenshots in my question. The second is expected behaviour, but this only happens once the taskbar is updated due to eg. opening another window. Before this, the taskbar looks like the first screenshot, which is wrong.

I understand better, I installed the two Tiny ISOs recently and I noticed that the dev deleted far too many things for the OS to be stable and we don't know what he did. I suppose he had to manipulate DLLs to disable certain things. Make your own ISO, personally I made mine with NTLITE my Windows can boot on a VM with 1CPU and 2GB ram even less

Tiny11 is not to blame in this case.
Windows task labels were since always limited in length, and were truncated
when that length was exceeded.
I'm more used to seeing the triple-points character at the end of the label
when it was truncated, but behavior may change across Windows versions.
This abrupt truncation is exactly what I'm seeing in my Windows 11
(which is not Tiny11).

I'm not saying the truncation of the text is the issue there, I mean that the item itself does not size correctly. My second screenshot looks fine, it's the first one that I consider buggy behaviour.

This might indeed be a problem with Tiny11.
